# Writepad Like Application iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, core-graphics

I want to create app that should let the users to write in their own handwriting. Simply it is a handwriting app.

I dont know where to start my development and what are the concepts i need to be study for this(Core Graphics or OpenGL ES).

Please give me any reference.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Sign up as an iOS developer, and watch any of these session videos which look even remotely related to what you want to do:

http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/

They will give you an overall idea of what each API is capable of, and after that you can start researching individual topics in the documentation or here on stack overflow.

Good luck!

Comment: So basically you said nothing.